# Kohana and extJS Project

Tags: extjs, kohana

Currently in the system analysis phase and I am looking at developing a system that uses Kohana for the backend and extjs to display and render my data. How feasible is this? Is it the right approach to start with? Any good tutorials would be welcome.

Thanks

Comment: If you never worked with instrument it can be not a good idea to start learning it in real project. So if you never used extjs - probably you should learn it before start.

Comment: I used it a bti in the v2 stage. I want to revisit it. Its not a full blown live project but rather an in house app. It would be more like read/learn and develop which kind of works for me a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can definitely use Kohana with ExtJS in your project. Kohana is just a HMVC framework for PHP. The feasibility factor is up to you. How complex your application is? Do you really need ExtJS or Is jQuery UI feasible? etc. You might want to read this [post from Kohana forum](http://forum.kohanaframework.org/discussion/4518/application-structure-for-ajaxdriven-rias-extjs-jquery-js-mvc..s/p1) to decide yourself.

ExtJS community also have a [Kohana module (Ext.Direct module)](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?100688-Ext.Direct-for-Kohana-3). You can download and use it as well if you plan to use Ext.Direct.

Comment: My app is not so massive, I was just having one of those what do I do moments and I think JQuery UI might just suit my needs. Thanks for the links. Currently going thru them.

Comment: Do you have any link to a working step by step example of setting up extjs and kohana?

Comment: unfortunately no.. Are you facing any particular issue?

Comment: None really, I have a fresh Kohana installation and was thinking I would get a Hello World ExtJS script running.